# Adding encrypted columns to a SQL Server database with always encrypted on

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server database, with always encrypted on. I am using command line sql (T-SQL) to update the database, and I want to add a column. I can't find the syntax for adding a column that is marked as encrypted.

I know I can add the column and then use SQL Server Management Studio to set it to encrypted, but I really want to do it in a batch job, hence the T-SQL commands.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you use Microsoft PowersHell rather than TSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no TSQL API for it by design:

> You can perform the above steps using SQL tools:
>
> SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)
>
> SQL Server PowerShell
>
> sqlpackage - which automate the setup process
>
> To ensure Always Encrypted keys and protected sensitive data are never
> revealed in plaintext to the database environment, the Database Engine
> can't be involved in key provisioning and data encryption, or
> decryption operations. Therefore, Transact-SQL (T-SQL) doesn't support
> key provisioning or cryptographic operations. For the same reason,
> encrypting existing data or re-encrypting it (with a different
> encryption type or a column encryption key) needs to be performed
> outside of the database (SQL tools can automate that).

[Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16)